# How to write the Bayesian network in to files like Hugin format or BNIF?

Tags: c++11

Any API for C++11? I am writing a piece of code that generates a Bayesian network which I wanted to write into a standard file format like Hugin, BNIF.

I tried to look but couldn't get the documentation as well.

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who shares this same query. I have found a [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fgcozman/Research/InterchangeFormat/) that answers it. Further, found a [implementation](https://gitlab.com/SCoRe-Group/SABNA-Release) as well.